# I can't add the ui.filters module in my angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to use the unique filter in my ng-options directive, but when I try to add the script file I get this error, I add the script file in the following way.

I downloaded the unique.js file from here https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js
then I add the script src like this

```
<script src="/SpringMVCTemplateAnn/resources/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/unique.js"></script>
```

then I add the module in my app like this

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'smart-table', 'http-auth-interceptor', 'ui.filters']);
```

but I get the following errors

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.filters

Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.filters%26p1
```

this is the content of the unique.js file

```
/**
 * Filters out all duplicate items from an array by checking the specified key
 * @param [key] {string} the name of the attribute of each object to compare for uniqueness
 if the key is empty, the entire object will be compared
 if the key === false then no filtering will be performed
 * @return {array}
 */

angular.module('ui.filters').filter('unique', function () {

  return function (items, filterOn) {

if (filterOn === false) {
  return items;
}

if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
  var hashCheck = {}, newItems = [];

  var extractValueToCompare = function (item) {
    if (angular.isObject(item) && angular.isString(filterOn)) {
      return item[filterOn];
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  };

  angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
    var valueToCheck, isDuplicate = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
      if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
        isDuplicate = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!isDuplicate) {
      newItems.push(item);
    }

  });
  items = newItems;
}
return items;


};

});
```

Comment: the module is not available for injection create a module

Comment: when I call the script like this  `<script src="/SpringMVCTemplateAnn/resources/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/unique.js"></script>` that unique.js file have the created module like in the link, it have the same content that the link I provide have, but only that I create da file and copy/pasted the content there

Comment: Do I need to modify the file that I downloaded? and instead of putting ui.filters should I put MyApp?, I edited my question with the content of the file, but is the same content that appears in the link